# How can we get location latitude and longitude when gps is off

Tags: android, gps

There is a situation when we are inside home or office or in shopping mall we cannot get GPS updates.How can we get the lat and lon of even when GPS is off. I know that we can get using NETWORK_PROVIDER but i want to know that can we get location updates when gps is off.If yes how can we get?

Comment: near by tower location

Comment: is that the only way to get location updates

Comment: last known position is there too but tower location is the closed to GPS location in most cases (accuracy wise)

Comment: I have googled it but i came to know about Criteria what actually is it?

Comment: Network provider use Cell Tower Triangulation. I suggest to read this article for more information http://wrongfulconvictionsblog.org/2012/06/01/cell-tower-triangulation-how-it-works/

Comment: Thanks KPBird I have read your Fused locations example.No will read this and get back to you

Comment: That article will tell us about the location using cell tower.You mean to say we have options other than GPS and Network Provider.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the location through **Network Provider**, Below is the sample code.

```
LocationManager lm = (LocationManager)getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

        if(lm.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER)){        
            lm.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 2000,0.0f,  new LocationListener() {

                @Override
                public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                }

                @Override
                public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                }

                @Override
                public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                }

                @Override
                public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                }
            }); 
        }
```

OR

if you want location through **GPS**. below is sample code.

```
if(lm.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER)){        
            lm.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 2000,0.0f,  new LocationListener() {

                @Override
                public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                }

                @Override
                public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                }

                @Override
                public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                }

                @Override
                public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                }
            }); 
        }
```

If you have any query Please comment. Thanks.

Comment: HI Vivek Is there any way to get location updates when gps is off other than network provider

Comment: I guess no. You can only know you last known location. i am putting some useful links. Please go through that hope it can be useful to you. 1. http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/location/strategies.html  2. http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2011/06/deep-dive-into-location.html

Answer (score 0):

You (usually) cannot get an acurate coordinate within a building.
Just forget it, and save your time.
Within a building, there are either reflexions from GPS signals from outside, giving at least 50m, but usually a much higher location offset.
Later and deeper in th ebuilding that will drop to eiter no location or if enabled to cell tower (usually 1000m accuracy).